# How to add thousands separator for all rows in a column in sql server

Tags: mysql, separator

I have a table "detail" with column "amount". I would like to add thousand separator comma to the value in "amount" column and limit to 2 decimal. For instance: 20123.45323 will be 20,123.45.

How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function in MySQL. It would look like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(amount, 2) FROM detail;
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to permanently format the value instead of formating the select value?